# How can I parse a javascript stack trace into the original stack trace after the fact?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack-trace

We have a javascript application in production. We do not deploy mapping files. When we get an exception that we didn't expect (that's why they are called *exceptions*), we are left with a stack trace against our minified code, something like:

```
Error from the UI: https://www.my-site.com/ "mn@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/main.f2912b75.chunk.js:1:126651
1249/Ru/i<@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/main.f2912b75.chunk.js:1:463723
Ru@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/main.f2912b75.chunk.js:1:467475
Ji@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2014633
Ua@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2023533
Cs@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2062099
vu@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2053592
mu@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2053515
su@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2050524
Xo/<@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2001895
t.unstable_runWithPriority@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2077296
Ko@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2001604
Xo@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2001842
Qo@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2001775
nu@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2047306
ba@https://www.my-site.com/static/js/2.fad31a53.chunk.js:2:2019008
"
 Extra Details: https://www.my-site.com/ {"componentStack":"
    in t
    in N
    in L
    in Suspense
    in n
    in Unknown
    in c
    in t
    in Unknown
    in sb
    in t
    in n"}
```

I am assuming there must be a utility that I can use where I can plug in that stack trace, pass it a pointer to the mapping files and get a human-readable version of that stack trace. I have looked around and found paid, hosted solutions that do something similar. Or more manual ones (where I would have to punch in every line:column combination), and I swear I saw a Node utility at some point, but I cannot find it anymore...

Is there such a utility?